# Cauchy-Binet formula proof confusion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-graph-theory

I am doing a project for a graph theory course and would like to prove the Matrix Tree Theorem. This proof uses the Cauchy-Binet formula which I need to prove first. I have found many different proofs of the formula but I am confused about one step. My basic understanding of linear algebra is holding me back.

I am confused about how

$\sum\limits_{1\leq k_1 < ,...,<k_m \leq n} A\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & ... & m\\
k_1 & k_2 & ... & k_m
\end{pmatrix}
\sum\limits_{\sigma \in S_m} \text{sgn}(\sigma)b_{{k}_{\sigma(1)}1}b_{{k}_{\sigma(2)}2}...b_{{k}_{\sigma(m)}m}$

is equal to

$\sum\limits_{1\leq k_1 < ,...,<k_m \leq n} A\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & ... & m\\
k_1 & k_2 & ... & k_m
\end{pmatrix}
B\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & ... & m\\
k_1 & k_2 & ... & k_m
\end{pmatrix}
$

This is the last line step from this proof https://planetmath.org/cauchybinetformula

I understand this is similar to [Cauchy-Binet Formula (Matrix Proof)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3244154/cauchy-binet-formula-matrix-proof)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Basically this is the definition of the determinant.

Comment: Thank you @Mick. Where could I find this definition?

Comment: E.g. at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant

Comment: Thank you @Mick. The answer I was looking for is that this is the Leibniz formula for the determinant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the determinant is expressed using the Leibniz formula for determinants.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants